# How to concatenate psql variables?

Tags: postgresql, psql

How can I concatenate two psql (PostgreSQL client) variables? I want to generate an absolute path by concatenating a directory path variable and a filename variable.

I've tried this:

```
\set path '/tmp/'
\set file 'foo'
\echo :path:file
```

But psql puts a space between the path and the file, and outputs:

```
/tmp/ foo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\set path '/tmp/'
\set file 'foo'
\set pf :path:file \echo :pf
/tmp/foo
```

Why does this work? I quote the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html):

> \set [ name [ value [ ... ] ] ]
>
> Sets the internal variable name to value or, if more than one value is given, to the **concatenation of all of them**. [...]

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Even better than mine

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
\set path /tmp/
\set file foo
\qecho :path:file \o | sed s/\ //
/tmp/foo
```

`\qecho` writes to the query output channel (unlike `\echo`, which writes to standard output).  `\o |` then redirects the output to the subsequent command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want either the || operator or the concat function:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: How do you use these with `\echo`?

Comment: This answer refers to concatenation in SQL while the question is about `psql` (the terminal interface).