# How to pass variable to PL/pgSQL code from the command line?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql, string-manipulation

I am running a psql script from the command line with variables something like:

```
psql ...... -v now_utc=$NOW_UTC
```

Then I want to use this in my script like:

```
$$
DECLARE
   _now_date timestamp := :now_utc;
BEGIN
  -- do something
END
$$
```

But I got an error like:

> ```
> syntax error at or near ':'
> ```

The script is fine once I change from `:now_utc` to `now()` and it works like a charm.

The question is how I can pass a variable from the command line to PL/pgSQL code?

Answer (score 10):

[The manual for psql:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION)

> Variable interpolation will not be performed within quoted SQL literals and identifiers.

The body of a `DO` statement (or function) *is* a quoted literal - dollar-quoted in this case, but all the same:

```
$$
DECLARE
   _now_date timestamp := :now_utc;
BEGIN
   -- do something
END
$$
```

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)

To enable SQL interpolation, do it *outside* the string and then concatenate - which gets tedious quickly ...

One way to make it simpler is to let Postgres do the string processing and then execute the result using `\gexec`. Call from psql:

```
SELECT format($$
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _now_date timestamp := %L;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%%', _now_date;
END
$do$;
$$, :'now_utc')\gexec
```

```
NOTICE:  2019-06-14 00:41:53.040879
DO
```

(`%` has a special meaning inside [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT), using `%%` to get a single `%` in the string.)

Also note the syntax `:'now_utc'` to get a quoted string.

- [How can I quote a named argument passed in to psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188925/939860)
- [How to concatenate psql variables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21044/how-to-concatenate-psql-variables/21131#21131)

To just use the current UTC timestamp, you don't need all this complication:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _now_date timestamp := now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%', _now_date;
END
$do$;
```

[`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statements are not meant to take parameters. It's **simpler** to create a (temporary) function and pass value(s) as function parameter(s) in the call:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.foo(_now_date timestamp)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%', _now_date;
END
$func$;
```

Call with SQL interpolation in psql:

```
SELECT pg_temp.foo(:'now_utc');
```

**Finally**, for passing *values*, you can also (ab)use a Postgres **"customized option"** (as session variable):

```
SET myvars.now_date TO :'now_utc';

DO
$do$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%', current_setting('myvars.now_date', true);
END
$do$;
```

Note that the the value is stored as `text` and you may need to cast.

Details:

- [Declaring variable for a whole script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213919/declaring-variable-for-a-whole-script/213921#213921)

But then you might skip the psql variable and set the option in Postgres directly ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, in my case, I have to use the value from  'now_utc'. I fix the issue by using a temporary table like ```CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_dates (now_date timestamp);
insert into tmp_dates values (:'now_utc');``` but obviously your solution is better .

Comment: @ŁukaszWoźniczka: I added one more alternative.

Comment: Thanks, @ErwinBrandstetter all of those works for me